# Java-Stream - Using filter and forEach for populating a Set

Tags: java, collections, java-stream, side-effects, java-16

I have a `Set<Person>` and I need to filter the content and then populate another set out of the given set.

I am fairly new to streams.

The first solution that I can think of is chaining `stream().filter().foreach()`

**Solution 1:**

```
private Set<Person> mapPerson(final Set<Student> student) {
        final Set<Person> person = new HashSet<>();
        student.stream()
            .filter(student1 -> Objects.nonNull(student.getAge()))
            .forEach(student1 -> person.add(Person.builder()
                .id(student1.getId())
                .status(student1.getStatus()))
                .build()));

        return person;
    }
```

But I am not sure if this can somehow be done by chaining `stream().filter().map()` ?

Would appreciate any help and also if it is possible to do it both ways, which is the preferred way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that, you don't need to create a set manually and then mutate it. You can obtain a set as a result of the execution of the stream pipeline.

> can somehow be done by chaining **stream().filter().map()** ?

First transform a stream of students `Stream<Student>` into a stream of person objects  `Stream<Person>` by applying the [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) operation, which expects a function that turns the element of the stream into another object of the desired type. So you need to place the logic for creation of a `Person` object that was used inside `forEach()` into `map()`.

And then apply `collect` passing as parameter `Collectors.toSet()`.

```
private Set<Person> mapPerson(final Set<Student> students) {

  return students.stream()
          .filter(student -> Objects.nonNull(student.getAge()))
          .map(student -> Person.builder()
                          .id(student.getId())
                          .status(student.getStatus())
                          .build())
          .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

> if it is possible to do it both ways, which is the preferred way?

The approach you are using is **discouraged** by the [**documentation**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects). Have a look at the quote below (*emphasize is mine*).

> As an example of how to transform a stream pipeline that
> **inappropriately** uses **side-effects** to one that does not, the following
> code searches a stream of strings for those matching a given regular
> expression, and puts the matches in a list.
>
> ```
>  ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
>  stream.filter(s -> pattern.matcher(s).matches())
>        .forEach(s -> results.add(s));  // Unnecessary use of side-effects!
> ```
>
> ... the **forEach()** can simply be replaced with a reduction operation that
> is **safer**, more **efficient**, and more **amenable to parallelization**:
>
> ```
>  List<String> results =
>      stream.filter(s -> pattern.matcher(s).matches())
>            .toList();  // No side-effects!
> ```

You shouldn't utilize `forEach` (as well as `peek`) which could operate only by causing side effects in situations when there's an alternative way to achieve the same result.

In this case, you can do it with a `collect()` (*as shown above*) or by using a plain `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Out of curiosity what is the difference between the 2 here exactly ? Is it just the mutation aspect or something else that I am missing ?

Comment: @newLearner In your code, set is being populated via side effects with `forEach()`. Which isn't encouraged to used if in the case when it's possible to by other means. And since in this case, there are other ways to achieve that, there's no reason to resort to `forEach`. Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects).

Comment: @newLearner In this case there will be no tragedy. Your initial code will get executed correctly. But as I set it's discouraged practice and more over it doesn't really buy you anything, conversely it makes the code more verbose and less expressive because you need to declare collection separately.